# New server, EE migration, PHP 5.4 issue

Tags: php, white-screen-of-death

We've just set up a new server with the identical set up of a previous server, with one small difference: php 5.4 instead of php 5.3.

This is an EE install, version 2.6.1.

When I go to the site I get the white screen of death, and `debug = 1` doesn't give me anything of use.

I tried digging through the execution path, adding an `echo('test')` and a `die()` after every line and the first thing that causes an issue is in `system/codeigniter/system/CodeIgniter.php` on line 88:

`get_config(array('subclass_prefix' => $assign_to_config['subclass_prefix']));`

If I comment this out, the next hiccup is at line 106:

`$BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');`

From my research, it appears that even 2.6.1 should be fine on php 5.4, so does anyone have any ideas on a) how to fix it without downgrading to 5.3 and b) how to debug it properly to find out what might be causing the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: To get the PHP errors to show, try removing the conditionals around the error reporting code in the main index.php and the CP index.php files all together.

Comment: Try to set `$config['send_headers'] = 'n';`.

Comment: Try `$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';` as a first step.

Comment: Urgh. It was a simple solution (Focuslab config environment issue) but I'm baffled why I couldn't get the normal error message to show up. Thanks for everyone's help, should I delete this ticket?

Comment: @RobHodges, nothing changed.

Most of the times I saw this white screen was on Chrome, but not on Firefox. So I figured it's a browser issue, not a server one. Sometimes the error occurs after the headers be sent and the browser get crazy, so you can't see the error report. My suggestion was intended just to help you see the report.

If possible, edit your question to focus on the white screen and post this answer. This way, we can help others.

Comment: Another trick is to disable gzip, see my answer on this issue: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/26385/189

Answer (score 1):

The white screen of death is often caused by this:

Sometimes EE is set to output content as Gzip data.  When a PHP error occurs, the PHP error spits out first, and but the browser is expecting content that it can un-zip.  So you get a white screen of death.

Disable the Gzip preference, and the content will be served with a different mime-type, and then you'll get the error message displaying properly above a page of regular HTML, because the browser interprets the data correctly.